# Layer 7 Mobile App Development Platform

Tags: mobile, layer, ca

All,

Just wanted to check to see if CA Layer 7 has any mobile app development platform? I am trying to find if there is any but couldn't. I saw only Mobile API access solutions from Layer7.

has anyone known and used any mobile app development platform from CA?

Thanks
Paul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should help you : CA Mobile API Gateway

reference: http://www.ca.com/us/securecenter/ca-mobile-api-gateway.aspx

We are planning to trial this API this month, I would update this answer again with the review.
I really feel afraid using these APIs related to the security from the mobile because the applications are so sensitive even a "." on these API can create havoc. 
And also, I don't know how secure the mobile connections would be but let's give a try on test servers!

Answer (score 0):

Does the Layer7 Mobile Access Gateway help you? The latest MAG (2.0, I think) works with Layer7 8.0.